# Checking OS mic mute from javascript (MediaRecorder's track.muted doesn't seem to work)

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, firefox, mediarecorder

I'm trying to detect mic mute from the OS in javascript. I am using MediaRecorder APIs to record the audio. I see a muted object present in the MediaRecorder's media track but it is not changing when I mute the mic from my keyboard shortcut(at OS level). Is there any way to detect this?
Thanks in advance.

current code:

```
track.getAudioTracks()[0].muted
```

In my case it stays true in chrome and false in firefox all the time.

(I've seen some of the questions related to this but none seem to answer it)